# Get 401 Error if i try to change twitch.tv status or game title

Tags: c#, oauth, twitch

I get an oauth token with the [Implicit Grant Flow](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/authentication.md#implicit-grant-flow) and the scope channel_editor. If I try to change the the channel title the answer from twitch server is 401 Token invalid or missing required scope.

Thats the code i try to change the channel status:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/innoszorn83");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("authorization", "OAuth " + cs_globals.oauth);
        request.AddHeader("accept", "application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"channel\":{\"status\":\"Hello World\"}}",
            ParameterType.RequestBody);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I get the oauth about a webbrowser control in my c# programm.

Comment: I found the solution. I have one error in my code. I doesn't change the scope to channel_editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I have one error in my code. I doesn't change the scope to channel_editor

Comment: Glad to hear that and thank you for coming back to post your answer. Not many people do this. Could you post the code that is needed to achieve this, to improve your answer for other user with the same problem?